# how to make the method run once for specific record on odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

i'm trying to do a method with a button the add the total value of a Bill to the value of another object it working well but every time I press the button it adds the total value of the bill to the other object value, I need anything make scenes to prevent adding the bill value multiple times , here is the code

```
class acc_inv_prop(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.invoice'

property_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="account.asset.asset", string="Property", required=False, )

def prop_up_value(self):
    self.property_id.value += self.amount_total
    pass
```

what I can do on the object account.asset.asset to check the current bill was added before and raise error and if the bill is a new one add it's value normally but also for one time only

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean a property just allow adding once?

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding something to the value of an account.asset.asset making me uncomfortable (Shouldn't you make a logic that determines the full value of the asset from the invoice?)

You would need an additional field to remember that you added the amount already:

```
class acc_inv_prop(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    property_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="account.asset.asset", string="Property", required=False, )
    property_last_added_value = fields.Float(string='Last Value Added to Property', readonly=True, digits=0)

    def prop_up_value(self):
        if self.property_last_added_value != self.amount_total:
            self.property_id.value -= self.property_last_added_value
            self.property_id.value += self.amount_total
            self.property_last_added_value = self.amount_total
```

Comment: this idea may prevent me from adding any another bill with the same total cost

Comment: the cost added is saved on each bill `account.invoice` next to property_id. so 2 invoices would each "rember" if their amount_total was already added or not. and adding two invoices by linking them to the asset with property_id would work fine i guess. (appart from the general idea of mixing manual inputs (asset value) with automatic inputs (adding an amount) could be dangerous, maybe you could add a value_incl_properties thats a computed field on the `account.asset.asset`)